# Dyanamic Variable names in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

For a series of similar named string how to I case them to a variable similar to php's $$variable ?

I have tried

```
{% for col in 1..cols %}
  {% set field = 'field'~col %}
  <td>
    {{ form_widget(form.field) }}
  </td>
{% endfor %}
```

But I get error property does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it:

```
{% for col in 1..cols %}
  {% set field = 'field'~col %}
  <td>
    {{ form_widget(attribute(form,field)) }}
  </td>
{% endfor %}
```